# Get elasticsearch documents older than a certain age in minutes

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a field in some of my documents if they've been individually queried before which is a unix timestamp:

```
"timelock": 1,561,081,724.254
```

Some documents don't have this if they've never been individually queried. I would like to also have a query that only returns documents that either DO NOT have the field or have the field but the difference between it's timestamp and the current time is greater than 10 minutes (600sec)

```
documents = es.search(index='index', size=10000, body={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                },


            ],
            "filter": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": [           

            ]
        }
    }})
```

So I guess in pseudo-code I'd do it like:

```
if 'timelock' exists:
    if current_time - 'timlock' > 600:
        include in query
    else:
        exclude from query
else:
    include in query
```

I'm using the python module for ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply using [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "timelock"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timelock": {
              "lt": "now-10m"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the route I went, my problem was it was storing the timestamp as a string, so I had to go and convert everything to update the time as an actual date, so I could use this. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of python syntax but what I can suggest via sudo code is to use the logic below:

```
compare_stamp = current_timestamp - 600
if 'timelock' exists:
    if timelock < compare_stamp:
        include document
    else:
        exclude document
else:
    include document
```

Since you can easily get the `compare_stamp` in python script. This value can then be used in elastic query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "timelock"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timelock": {
              "lt": compare_timestamp
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```